# AngularJS ng-repeat over collection with mutliple data type elements but filtering just the date fields

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat over a collection that has fields of different data types. I would like to format just the date fields using something like {{mydate | date}}, however, how do I just do this for only the date fields and not the other string fields in the collection?

This is my code:

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="item in myItems">{{item.title}}</li></ul>
```

Thanks all!

Comment: We'll need to see more of your code and some more information in order to help

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this you may try the following:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat-start="item in myItems">{{item.title}}</li>
    <li>{{item.date | date}}</li>
    <li ng-repeat-end>{{item.price}}</li>
</ul>
```

The `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` allows you to repeat over more than one element, which is what you want to do, from what I can tell from your description.